# Optimal Pattern or Model for parameterized data driven testing Webdriver & Java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, parameter-passing

I should preface this by saying that I am a relative novice to Java so this is probably quite an easy one to crack in terms of a simple and efficient solution.  I simply haven’t  familiarized with patterns very much yet!

I have a need to automate the population of form field data in a web app using Webdriver and Java.

I have a number of properties: “house1”, “house2”, “house3” to select from a dropdown at the top of the form.

If I select “house1” I must populate the address with “123 The Boulevard”
If I select “house2” I must populate the address with “101 Ocean Drive” etc...

I can think of 2 ways of organizing this in my Junit/Webdriver/Java setup:

1:
Use JUnit 4’s @RunWith(Parameterized.class) feature
wherein  I read each house name in from a flat file (.csv for example) and pass it in so the test is invoked once each time for each of the 3 rows of data (house names):-

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    driver.get(this.house);
}

@Test
public void oakLeafIconPresent(){

    WebElement formfieldOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//formFieldOne"));

    switch (house) {
        case "house1": {
            formfieldOne.sendKeys("123 The Boulevard");
        }
        break;
        case "house2": {
            formfieldOne.sendKeys("101 Ocean Drive");
        }
        break;
        case "house3": {
            formfieldOne.sendKeys("1 Amityville");
        }
```

This seems expensive to me.

2.Create a bespoke method for each house that needs data population and call on demand when required:

```
   private void fillFormOneForHouseOne(){

    WebElement formfieldOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//formFieldOne"));
    formfieldOne.sendKeys("123 The Boulevard");

}

private void fillFormOneForHouseTwo(){

    WebElement formfieldOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//formFieldOne"));
    formfieldOne.sendKeys("101 Ocean Drive");

}
```

This seems even worse.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend reading up on the Page Object Model and selenium in general. Check out the selenium documents or [here](http://blog.activelylazy.co.uk/2011/07/09/page-objects-in-selenium-2-0/) is a article about the Page Object Model.

Comment: That is a good point, though I think it is more suitable for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do it.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class House {

  static WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     Select select = new Select(select_house_type());
     select.selectByValue("house1");
     formFieldOne().sendKeys(getStreetName("house1"));
  }

  public static WebElement select_house_type(){
    //I dont prefer to use xpath since it for me doesnt work all the time, so i use cssSelector
    return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id*='select_house_type']"));
  }
  public static WebElement formFieldOne(){
    //I dont prefer to use xpath since it for me doesnt work all the time, so i use cssSelector
    return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='formFieldOne']"));
  }

  public static String getStreetName(String key){

//    Keep all data seperated

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("house1", "123 The Boulevard");
    map.put("house2", "101 Ocean Drive");
    map.put("house3", "1 Amityville");

    return (String)map.get(key);


  }
}
```